# Amending a differential geometry formula

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, connections

I'm reading my professor's notes on Differential Geometry. In the chapter regarding connections he deals with torsion and there is an observation in which he affirms that if $\alpha$ is a 1-form and $\nabla$ is a zero torsion connection then the following hols:
\begin{equation}
\alpha(X,Y) = (\nabla_X\alpha)(Y) - (\nabla_Y\alpha)(X)
\end{equation}
I'm trying to make sense of this equation but I think there is a typo of some  sort. Am I missing something or should this formula be amended?

Comment: How can a $1$-form eat two vector fields $X$ and $Y\,?$

Comment: That's why I suppose it's a typo but how should it read to have a meaning?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I guess the formula your professor intended is
$$
d \alpha(X,Y) = (\nabla_X \alpha)Y - (\nabla_Y \alpha)X.
$$
This is true because, you can prove that $d\alpha$ acts on a pair of vectors as
$$
d \alpha(X,Y) = X(\alpha(Y)) - Y(\alpha(X)) - \alpha([X,Y]). \tag{1}
$$

A connection is symmetric (or torsion-free) if
$$
\nabla_X Y - \nabla_Y X = [X,Y]
$$
so (1) equals to
$$
d \alpha(X,Y) = X(\alpha(Y)) - Y(\alpha(X)) - \alpha(\nabla_X Y) + \alpha(\nabla_Y X). \tag 2
$$

By definition, or because of the properties of the natural dual connection, the covariant derivative of a 1-form has the following expression:
$$
(\nabla_X \alpha)Y = X(\alpha(Y)) - \alpha(\nabla_X Y)
$$
therefore (2) equals
$$
d \alpha(X,Y) =   (\nabla_X \alpha)Y - (\nabla_Y \alpha)X.
$$

Comment: Good sleuthing!